# Possible reasons for groovy program running as kubernetes job dumping threads during execution

Tags: bash, kubernetes, groovy, jvm, threadpool

I have a simple groovy script that leverages the `GPars` library's `withPool` functionality to launch HTTP GET requests to two internal API endpoints in parallel.

The script runs fine locally, both directly as well as a docker container.

When I deploy it as a Kubernetes `Job` (in our internal EKS cluster: `1.20`), it runs there as well, but the moment it hits the first `withPool` call, I see a giant thread dump, but the execution continues, and completes successfully.

**NOTE**: Containers in our cluster run with the following pod security context:

```yaml
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1000
```

**Environment**

```sh
# From the k8s job container
groovy@app-271df1d7-15848624-mzhhj:/app$ groovy --version
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.foreign, jdk.incubator.vector
Groovy Version: 4.0.0 JVM: 17.0.2 Vendor: Eclipse Adoptium OS: Linux


groovy@app-271df1d7-15848624-mzhhj:/app$ ps -ef 
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
groovy       1     0  0 21:04 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash bin/run-script.sh
groovy      12     1 42 21:04 ?        00:00:17 /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -Xms3g -Xmx3g --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -classpath /opt/groovy/lib/groovy-4.0.0.jar -Dscript.name=/usr/bin/groovy -Dprogram.name=groovy -Dgroovy.starter.conf=/opt/groovy/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Dgroovy.home=/opt/groovy -Dtools.jar=/opt/java/openjdk/lib/tools.jar org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter --main groovy.ui.GroovyMain --conf /opt/groovy/conf/groovy-starter.conf --classpath . /tmp/script.groovy
groovy     116     0  0 21:05 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
groovy     160   116  0 21:05 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

**Script (relevant parts)**

```
@Grab('org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1')
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
final def jsl = new JsonSlurper()


//...

while (!(nextBatch = getBatch(batchSize)).isEmpty()) {
    def devThread = Thread.start {
        withPool(poolSize) {
            nextBatch.eachParallel { kw ->
                String url = dev + "&" + "query=$kw"
                try {
                    def response = jsl.parseText(url.toURL().getText(connectTimeout: 10.seconds, readTimeout: 10.seconds,
                            useCaches: true, allowUserInteraction: false))
                    devResponses[kw] = response
                } catch (e) {
                    println("\tFailed to fetch: $url | error: $e")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def stgThread = Thread.start {
        withPool(poolSize) {
            nextBatch.eachParallel { kw ->
                String url = stg + "&" + "query=$kw"
                try {
                    def response = jsl.parseText(url.toURL().getText(connectTimeout: 10.seconds, readTimeout: 10.seconds,
                            useCaches: true, allowUserInteraction: false))
                    stgResponses[kw] = response
                } catch (e) {
                    println("\tFailed to fetch: $url | error: $e")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    devThread.join()
    stgThread.join()
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM groovy:4.0.0-jdk17 as builder

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq bash curl wget jq

WORKDIR /app

COPY bin /app/bin

RUN chmod +x /app/bin/*

USER groovy
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
CMD ["bin/run-script.sh"]
```

The `bin/run-script.sh` simply downloads the above groovy script at runtime and executes it.

```sh
wget "$GROOVY_SCRIPT" -O "$LOCAL_FILE"

...

groovy "$LOCAL_FILE"
```

As soon as the execution hits the *first* call to `withPool(poolSize)`, there's a giant thread dump, but execution continues.

I'm trying to figure out *what* could be causing this behavior. Any ideas ‍♂️?

[Thread dump](https://pastebin.com/Th7P7USQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, answering my own question here.

The issue turned out to be [this log4j2 JVM hot-patch](https://github.com/aws-samples/kubernetes-log4j-cve-2021-44228-node-agent) that we're currently leveraging to fix the recent log4j2 vulnerability. This agent (running as a `DaemonSet`) patches all running JVMs in all our k8s clusters.

This, somehow, causes my OpenJDK `17` based app to thread dump. I found the same issue with an ElasticSearch `8.1.0` deployment as well (also uses a pre-packaged OpenJDK `17`). This one is a service, so I could see a thread dump happening pretty much every half hour! Interestingly, there are other JVM services (and some SOLR `8` deployments) that *don't* have this issue ‍♂️.

Anyway, I worked with our devops team to temporarily *exclude* the node that deployment was running on, and lo and behold, the thread dumps disappeared!

Balance in the universe has been restored ‍♂️.